# has_many :through Rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**Updated the question as original was over simplistic, thanks to Aaron McLeod aka AGMCLEOD for your help highlighting this**

---

My problem is such that it is not that I cannot get it to work, but getting it to work how I want.

**The problem**

Imagine 3 models, a Company, Branch and a Contact, they are linked together through a CompanyContacts model or a look-up table.

The table company_contacts looks like this:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| company_id | branch_id | contact_id |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

and my ideal statements for relating a contact to a branch and company should be:

```
update company_contacts set contact_id = x where branch_id = y AND company_id = z
```

So the question, How is this possible using ActiveRecord? Do you create custom methods to set it in one go?

What I have in my models

**CompanyContact Model**

```
belongs_to :company, :class_name => "Company", :foreign_key => :company_id
belongs_to :branch,  :class_name => "Branch",  :foreign_key => :branch_id
belongs_to :contact, :class_name => "Contact", :foreign_key => :contact_id
```

**Company Model**

```
has_many :company_contacts
has_many :branches,  :through => :company_contacts, :source => :branches
has_many :contacts,  :through => :company_contacts, :source => :contacts
```

**Branch Model**

```
has_many :company_contacts
has_many :companies, :through => :company_contacts, :source => :companies
has_many :contacts,  :through => :company_contacts, :source => :contacts
```

I would love to be able to do the following but it is not possible

```
has_one :company, :through => :company_contacts, :source => :company
```

Of course I could simulate it by

```
def branch
  Branch.companies.first
end
```

**Contact Model**

```
has_many :company_contacts
has_many :branches, :through => :company_contacts, :source => :branches
has_many :companies, :through => :company_contacts, :source => :companies
```

Again ideally i would like to have, has_one branch and has_one company

My current solution when creating a contact and << to a branch results in two rows being created

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| company_id | branch_id | contact_id |
+------------+-----------+------------+
| 1          | 1         | nil        |
+------------+-----------+------------+
| nil        | 1         | 1          |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

When, what in fact I would like to achieve is:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| company_id | branch_id | contact_id |
+------------+-----------+------------+
| 1          | 1         | 1          |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

The only way I can think of doing this is creating a custom method

I will continue to try and resolve my issue and post my findings
Look forward to your replies

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok after a hell of a lot more digging around after posting the question I came across this awesome answer to something similar. zetetic provided a very detailed answer and I read up in a little more depth on how to resolve this issue.

First the inspiration: [has_many :through multiple has_one relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987541/has-many-through-multiple-has-one-relationships)

**Now the answer:**

In the create method in your ContactController the magic 1 line of code is:

```
@contact.company_contacts.build(:company_id => @company.id, :branch_id => @branch.id)
```

So in full in ContactController's create method:

```
# fetch the branch and company ids first

@contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
@contact.company_contacts.build(:company_id => @company.id, :branch_id => @branch.id)
@contact.save
```

and it does exactly what I wanted to achieve with:

```
INSERT INTO "company_contacts" ("branch_id", "company_id", "contact_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["branch_id", 2], ["company_id", 4], ["contact_id", 12]]
```

Phew - took me a while for some reason and seems so simple looking at it!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you can do something like the following. Assuming you're passing the branch id and company id through the form, or if you have it already in the url.

```
def create
  @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
  if @contact.save
    cc = CompanyContact.new(:contact_id => @contact.id, :branch_id => params[:branch_id], :company_id => params[:company_id])
    cc.save
    redirect_to contacts_url, :notice => "Contact saved"
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

You might need to adjust parameter names and such, but that should work. Because it is a bit of three way connection, I'm not sure if there's a way to build it right on the contact object.

Comment: actually completely agree with you but in reality the Models are different. Think about it differently say for Company, Branch, Contact for example - I suppose this would have been a better example to use as i have clearly over simplified the problem. The reason I am doing this is for efficiency and less queries.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes more sense then. Are you still able to post the code you're using in the controller? I'm a pretty visual person, and that might help. I'll adjust my answer for how I would think it would be done though.