# father/mother/children relationships in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, self-reference, mongoid3

I have the same problem as described here [has_many :through multiple has_one relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987541/has-many-through-multiple-has-one-relationships)

But I use Mongoid instead ActiveRecord. And I have a problem in relations has_one, because they do not have :through.

How to solve this problem? Or reject the above solutions?

PS: I'm using rails 3.2.8 and mongoid 3.

Thanks